# Return results based on distinct on certain column in one situation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I want to return the most recent (dateCreated desc) of each record in two different situations.

This might not even be possible, but thought I'd reach out on here.

1) if the record has a value in the parentId column, then I want to search thru all the records with that same parentId and include only the one that is the most recent (dateCreated desc) in the results.

I know how to do that w/ a query like this:

```
select distinct(parentId) from table order by dateCreated desc
```

But I don't know how to accomplish that while trying to account for both situations.

2) if the record does not contain a parentId and that record's ID is not in another record's parentId, then include that in the result.

I know I could get all the results, then programmatically loop thru it like so:

```
for($i<0; $i<count($results); $i++)
{
   if ($results[$i]['parentId'])
   {
      $parentId = $results[$i]['parentId'];
      $parentDateCreated = $results[$i]['dateCreated'];

      for($k=0; $k<count($results); $k++)
      {
         if($results[$k]['parentId'] = $parentId)
         {
            if ( $results[$i]['dateCreated'] < $results[$k]['dateCreated'] )
            {
                $data[$parentId] = $results[$i];
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Probably not efficient and not sure if it works, but wanted to give an idea of what I need to accomplish, I need to find the most recent records in the case that it has a value in the parentId (which it needs to be compared with all other records with the same parentId) or if the record does not contain a parentId, then just include that in the result as well.

I created sql fiddle with a basic query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69544/1

Sample data:

```
id  parentId  dateCreated
--  --------  -------------------
1   null      2016-04-10 20:00:00
2   1         2016-04-12 12:00:00
3   1         2016-04-13 10:00:00
4   null      2016-04-15 14:33:00
```

Expected results (I'll just return the ids I expect in the result):

3 and 4.

id 3, because it found a parentId of 1 and found the most recent one in id 3 because of the dateCreated was more recent.

id 4, because it did not have a parentId and nor did 4 show up in any other record's parentId column.

Comment: Your first query won't work.  Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Your fiddle is not very helpful, since you don't have multiple records with the same parentID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UNION` of two queries. One query gets the most `dateCreated` for each `parentID` where that field is not null. The other query returns all the records where `parentID` is null.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT parentId, MAX(dateCreated) AS maxCreate
      FROM yourTable
      WHERE parentID IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY parentID) AS t2
ON t1.parentID = t2.parentID AND t1.dateCreated = t2.maxCreate
UNION
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE parentID IS NULL
AND id NOT IN (
    select parentID 
    from yourTable
    WHERE parentId IS NOT NULL)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f9b0/7)

Comment: I modified the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b348a/3 I added another record to the table and modified your query above to include recipientId = 1, in that fiddle, your query returns ids: 3, 1, 5. I expect it to return just 3 and 5, because id 3 has a parentId of 1, since that is newer (dateCreated is higher) then return that instead of id 1 and id 5 because it has a recipientId = 1 and no parentId so it does not need to look to see if there is another id that is newer like in the case of id 3. Thanks for providing feedback to my question.

Comment: `id = 1` has no `parentId`, so it gets returned.

Comment: The updated fiddle still doesn't have two rows with the same `parentId`.

Comment: It would be easier if you removed all the irrelevant columns from the fiddle.

Comment: I updated it to only include the necessary columns. In this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f9b0/2/0, I expect it to return ids: 5, 6 and 7. id 5 because it has a recipientId =1 and the most recent dateCreated date with the parentId of 1. id 6 because it has a recpientId = 1 and it does not have to worry about any other rows because parentId is null, id 7 because it has the most recent (dateCreated) where parentId is 4 and recipientId = 1

Comment: The question says "if the record does not contain a parentId, then just include that in the result as well." So it includes all records with no `parentId`, that's why 1 and 4 are in the result.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, if the record does not contain a parentId and that record's ID is not in another record's parentId, then include that in the result.

Comment: Just add that condition to the second query in the union. I've updated the answer.